# How to improve responsiveness of ipython interact for matplotlib 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, mplot3d

Python 2.7.9, matplotlib 1.4.0, ipython 2.3.1, macbook pro retina

I am using ipython's interact() with a 3D plot in an ipython notebook, but find that the graph updates too slowly when changing a slider control. Here is example code that has this problem when run:

```
from IPython.html.widgets import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import math
%matplotlib inline

def plt3Dsin(angle):
    npnts = 100
    rotationangle_radians = math.radians(angle)
    tab_x = np.linspace(0,3,npnts)
    tab_y = np.zeros(npnts)
    tab_z = np.sin(2.0*np.pi*tab_x)
    yrotate = tab_z * np.sin(rotationangle_radians)
    zrotate = tab_z * np.cos(rotationangle_radians)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    ax.plot(tab_x, yrotate, zrotate)
    ax.set_xlim3d([0.0,3.0])
    ax.set_ylim3d([-1.0,1.0])
    ax.set_zlim3d([-1.0,1.0])
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('z')

interact(plt3Dsin,angle=(0,360,5));
```

I have tried to separate out the figure and axes creation from actual plotting in the following code, but the first time I change the slider the graph doesn't update and the 2nd time I change it the graph disappears altogether. I assume I'm doing something wrong, but have not been able to figure out what. (The use of globals below is just a quick expedient approach for this simple example code.)

```
npnts = 100
tab_x = np.linspace(0,3,npnts)
def init_plt3Dsin():
    global fig
    global ax
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.plot([], [], [], lw=2)
    ax.set_xlim3d([0.0,3.0])
    ax.set_ylim3d([-1.0,1.0])
    ax.set_zlim3d([-1.0,1.0])
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('z')
def plt3Dsin(angle):
    global fig
    global ax
    rotationangle_radians = math.radians(angle)
    tab_y = np.zeros(npnts)
    tab_z = np.sin(2.0*np.pi*tab_x)
    yrotate = tab_z * np.sin(rotationangle_radians)
    zrotate = tab_z * np.cos(rotationangle_radians)
    ax.plot(tab_x, yrotate, zrotate)
init_plt3Dsin()
interact(plt3Dsin,angle=(0,360,5));
```

Comment: try using the `nbagg` backend?

Comment: Funny you should ask. I just happened to come across the existence of nbagg this morning on the ipython dev list. I just tried it and found that it does result in much faster plot updates using the original code block I posted. Why is that and what exactly is nbagg? Can you point me to any documentation or information?

Comment: See the 1.4.0 release notes

Answer (score 0):

tcaswell's comment suggesting the use of the nbagg backend offered a good way to address my problem in that it made the first code block run fast enough to be satisfactory.